# Homology Group of $SO(4)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

I was trying to calculate the homology groups $H_1(SO(4))$, $H_2(SO(4))$ and $H_3(SO(4))$, but I have no clue on how to do this.

I calculate other homology groups, for like the sphere $S^n$, projective spaces $\mathbb C\mathbb P^n$ and $\mathbb R\mathbb P^n$, the Klein bottle and so on. All these homology groups I could use some relation, like the Meyer-Vietoris sequence, or use that the inclusion was a cofibration.

The only thing that I know is that $SO(4)\cong SO(3)\times S^3 $, but still I dont know how to compute $H_n(X\times Y)$.

What could I try to do that?

Thank in advance.

Comment: You can use Kunneth's theorem. Since $S^3$ has free integral homology, the canonical map provided by the theorem is an isomorphism.

Comment: You can use Mayer-Vietoris easily to do the homology of $X\times S^n$, writing $S^n$ as the union of two thickened hemispheres.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I actually don't learn yet the Kunneth's theorem, but I have looked for it and I find that $H_k(X\times S^n)\cong H_k(X)\oplus H_{k−n}(X)$, this seems useful, but what to do in the cases that $k-n<0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin For the other sugestion, my choice of $X_1$ and $X_2$ should be the sphere minus the north and minus the south poles? In that case I got that $X_1\cap X_2=SO(3)\times S^2$, and looks trouble doing it over and over to solve.

Comment: @e.turatti If $k-n<0$ then that term is $0$.

Comment: This seems to solve all my problems, thanks so much. If you want to answer I will give you the right answer.

Comment: You can use the fact that homology commutes with suspension on spaces and suspension on graded abelian groups, followed by the fact that it satisfies the wedge axiom. $H^*(X\times Y)\cong H^{*+1}(\Sigma *(X\times Y))\cong H^*(\Sigma X\vee \Sigma Y\vee \Sigma (X\wedge Y))\cong H^{*+1}(\Sigma X)\oplus H^{*+1}(\Sigma Y)\oplus H^{*+1}(\Sigma X\wedge Y)\cong  H^*(X)\oplus H^*(Y)\oplus H^*(X\vee Y)$.